# Why do I keep getting the error: An error was encountered: name 'tf' is not defined when trying to load a model on one of core instances in EMR?

Tags: apache-spark, tensorflow, keras, amazon-emr

I am trying to %%spark on an EMR cluster to make predictions in parallel on multiple files using a pretrained keras model. I can load the model on the master node and do predictions with it, but when I try to use spark I get the error "name 'tf' is not defined" when trying to use or access the model.

Up to now I have tried the following solutions and they all produce the same error:

1. I have tried passing the model in a lambda wrapper.
2. I have broadcasted the model using sc.broadcast
3. I downloaded the model.h5 on all nodes and usee load_model for each partition. For   load_model I have used the custom_objects={'tf': tf} solution and also I am importing tensorflow as tf in the wrapper function where the model is loaded.

None of the solutions worked. Did anyone had any similar experience? I am using r5 instances for the master and m5 instances for the nodes.

Comment: `%%spark on an EMR cluster to make predictions` from where? EMR Notebook? or on the cluster shell itself?

Comment: From notebook in sagemaker.